# Terminal window automatically closes when using Scrapy shell to scrape a JSON file

Tags: python, json, shell, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently working on a webscraper that is suppposed to scrape data from a a few different sites and across all of these sites, one element has to be accessed by finding the JSON file that each site uses to load its data asynchronously (specifically, the ticket price and other data for events). I have so far successfully been able to both test in the shell and run in the crawl spider the scraping of the lowest ticket price from JSON files like [these](https://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=1782609) for [this website](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html), but for some reason, I have had problems even accessing such JSON files from the scrapy shell.

When I tried to access this [file](https://seatgeek.com/listings?client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=2549305&_wt=1&&_=1436304908081/) for [this site](https://seatgeek.com/awolnation-tickets), the shell stalls and never brings up the command line. The shell only terminates when I press enter. Upon trying this [file](https://www.ticketcity.com/Catalog/public/v1/events/1324241/ticketblocks?P=0,99999999&q=0&per_page=250&page=1&sort=p.asc&f.t=s&_=1436305633669) for [this site](https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/rock-and-pop/awolnation-tickets.html) in the shell, the entire terminal window automatically closes. Is there something different about these files that keeps them from being scraped or is it just a system error.

If it is that there is something blocking web crawlers here (I'm still new to using json btw), are there any alternatives to accessing the files in this way such as maybe downloading the JSON first and then parsing it (I'm still new to using json btw)? I need to scrape the price from JSON files from a few more sites so I just wanted to make sure that the problem wouldn't persist. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 inside of Virtual Box.

Comment: How are you launching the process/task/etc. when these fail?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I just used the command: scrapy shell <the link>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do here is to start up the shell first:

```
scrapy shell
```

And then call the [`fetch(url)`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#available-shortcuts):

```
$ scrapy shell
In [1]: import json
In [2]: fetch("https://seatgeek.com/listings?client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=2549305&_wt=1&&_=1436304908081/")
In [3]: data = json.loads(response.body)
```

Aside from that, make sure you are using the most up-to-date Scrapy 1.0.